# Solving Stochastic Differential Equation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, stochastic

I need some help to generate a MATLAB program in order to answer the following question. Can somebody help me in this regard? Any sort of hint that could be helpful will surely be appreciated...

Q: "Simulate `N = 10` baches with `M = 100` trajectories of the Ito Process X satisfying the following SDE:

```
dXt = μ·X_t·dt + σ·X_t·dB_t.
```

with `X₀ = 1`, `μ = 1.5`, `σ = 1.0` and their Euler approximations with equidistant time steps of size `Δ = 2⁴` corresponding to the same sample paths of the Wiener process on the time interval `[0,T]` for `T = 1`. Evaluate the 90% confidence interval for the absolute error."

I have created the following code on MATLAB for the above question. Can somebody correct me if I'm wrong somewhere. As well as help me how to simulate batches as well as 90% confidence interval.

```
randn('state',100)
a=1.5; b=1; Xzero=1;
T=1; n=2^8; dt=T/n;
M = 100;

Xerr = zeros(M,1);
for s = 1:M

    dW = sqrt(dt)*randn(1,n);
    W = cumsum(dW);
    Xtrue = Xzero*exp((a-0.5*b^2)+b*W(end));
    R  = 2^5;
    Dt = R*dt; L=n/R;

    Xtemp = Xzero;
    for j=1:L
        Winc=sum(dW(R*(j-1)+1:R*j));
        Xtemp=Xtemp+Dt*a*Xtemp+b*Xtemp*Winc;
    end

    Xerr(s,1) = abs(Xtemp-Xtrue);

end
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a programming question in here.  Can you say what's wrong in the implementation that you're trying to fix?

Comment: I just need to know how we can simulate batches.

Comment: Just how to keep the data from multiple runs? Wrap in `for j=1:1000`, change to `Xerr=zeros(M,1000)`, `Xerr(s,j)=...`  If more, could you please hone the question.  The details of the model don't seem relevant if that's the case.

Comment: @Josha Goldberg If I put what you have suggested will I get what I need.

Comment: i think you can get some idea from this page :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268094/stochastic-differential-equations-sde-in-2-dimensions?rq=1 .