# Stochastic Differential Equations (SDE) in 2 dimensions

Tags: matlab, math, stochastic

I am working on stochastic differential equations for the first time. I am looking to simulate and solve a stochastic differential equations in two dimensions.

The model is as follows:

> dp=F(t,p)dt+G(t,p)dW(t)

where:

- p is a 2-by-1 vector: p=(theta(t); phi(t))
- F is a column vector: F=(sin(theta)+Psi* cos(phi); Psi*
  cot(theta)*sin(phi))
- G is a 2-by-2 matrix: G=(D 0;0 D/sin(theta))
- Psi is a parameter and D is the diffusion constant

I wrote code as follows:

```
function MDL=gyro_2dim(Psi,D)
% want to solve for 2-by-1 vector:
%p=[theta;phi];
%drift function
F=@(t,theta,phi)  [sinth(theta)+Psi.*cos(phi)-D.*cot(theta);Psi.*cot(theta).*sin(phi)];
%diffusion function
G=@(t,theta,phi) [D 0;0 D./sin(theta)];
MDL=sde(F,G)
end
```

Then I call the function with the following script:

```
params.t0   = 0;               % start time of simulation
params.tend = 20;              % end time
params.dt =0.1;                % time increment
D=0.1;
nPeriods=10; % # of simulated observations
Psi=1;
MDL=gyro_2dim(Psi,D);
[S,T,Z]=simulate(MDL, nPeriods,'DeltaTime',params.dt);
plot(T,S)
```

When I run the code, I receive this error message:

> Drift rate invalid at initial conditions or inconsistent model
>   dimensions.

Any idea how to fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for [`sde`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/sde.html):

> User-defined drift-rate function, denoted by `F`. `DriftRate` is a function that returns an `NVARS`-by-1 drift-rate vector when called with two inputs:
>    - A real-valued scalar observation time `t`.
>    - An `NVARS`-by-1 state vector `Xt`.

A similar specification is provided for the `Diffusion` function. However, you're passing in the elements of your state vector as scalars and thus have three, rather than two, inputs. You can try changing your model creation function to:

```
function MDL=gyro_2dim(Psi,D)
% State vector: p = [theta;phi];
F = @(t,p)[sin(p(1))+Psi.*cos(p(2))-D.*cot(p(1));
           Psi.*cot(p(1)).*sin(p(2))];            % Drift
G = @(t,p)[D 0;
           0 D./sin(p(1))];                       % Diffusion
MDL = sde(F,G);
MDL.StartTime = 0;   % Set initial time
MDL.StartState = ... % Set initial conditions
```

I also changed `sinth(theta)` to `sin(p(1))` as there is no `sinth` function. I can't test this as I don't have the Financial toolbox (few do).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did modify the function as you said but still I have the same error message: Drift rate invalid at initial conditions or inconsistent model dimensions.

Comment: @Mari: How are you setting your initial conditions and initial time? You need to set the `StartState` and `StartTime` properties of the `MDL` object. I have no idea what happens if you don't set these, but your drift function will return `[-Inf;NaN]` if it defaults to `[0;0]` for your initial conditions, which will be bad.